# Is a subquotient of an unramified principal series unramified?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

The answer to this question may be true in a much more general setting, but I ask it in the precise case I need it.

Let $G$ be the unramified unitary group $U(3)$, built out of an unramified extension $E/F$ over a local non-Archimedean field $F$. Let $H$ be the subgroup $U(2)$ embedded "in the corners" (but maybe it works with any subgroup), that is to say
$$U(2) \ni \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix} \longmapsto \begin{pmatrix}a & & b \\ & 1 & \\ c & & d\end{pmatrix} \in U(3).$$

Let $(\pi, V)$ be a generic irreducible admissible representation of $G(F)$. Say we have an $s \in \mathbb{C}$ such that
$$\operatorname{dim} \mathrm{Hom}_H(V, \operatorname{Ind}_{B_H}^H \lvert\cdot\rvert^s) = 1,$$
where $B_H$ is a Borel of $H$. The representation $\operatorname{Ind}_{B_H}^H \lvert\cdot\rvert^s$ is an unramified principal series of $H$. Letting $K$ be a maximal compact subgroup of $G$, we know that $K_H := K \cap H$ is a maximal compact subgroup of $H$, and so $\operatorname{Ind}_{B_H}^H \lvert\cdot\rvert^s$ has a $K_H$-fixed vector. The question is:

> Can we deduce that $\pi$ also has a $K_H$-fixed vector?

Maybe this is the case even without the one-dimensionality of $\operatorname{Hom}_H(V, \operatorname{Ind}_{B_H}^H \lvert\cdot\rvert^s)$?

Comment: I think Jonathan Cohen has proven this in unpublished notes of his.

Comment: Is $\pi$ meant to be an irreducible representation of $G(F)$, or only of $H(F)$?  If the latter, then what rôle does $G$ play? \\ Also, TeX note: $\operatorname{dim} \ldots$ `\operatorname{dim} \ldots` gives the proper operator spacing automatically, saving the need for something like $\mathrm{dim}\, \ldots$ `\mathrm{dim}\, \ldots`.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: The idea is that the map $V \to \mathrm{Ind}_{B_H}^{H} |\cdot|^s$ is surjective since the dimension of this Hom-space is $1$. Moreover, if $C$ is a compact open subgroup of $H$, then taking $C$-fixed vectors is an exact functor. Since $\mathrm{Ind}_{B_H}^{H} |\cdot|^s$ has a $K_H$-fixed vector, this means that $\pi$ must also have a $K_H$-fixed vector.

Comment: @LSpice I mean irreducible for $G$ indeed. Thanks for the TeX note.

Comment: @PeterHumphries I was indeed hoping for an argument along these lines, using the exactness of "$C$-fixed vectors". However I should be missing a point: why does the one-dimensionality of the Hom-space imply that $V\to\mathrm{Ind}_{B_H}^H |\cdot|^s$ is surjective? (If I understand this point, then I agree with your argument).

Comment: We can assume that $\mathrm{Ind}_{B_H}^H |\cdot|^s$ is irreducible. Given a linear map $T \in \mathrm{Hom}_H (V,\mathrm{Ind}_{B_H}^H |\cdot|^s)$, the image of $V$ under $T$ is a $H$-invariant subspace of $\mathrm{Ind}_{B_H}^H |\cdot|^s$, thus is either all of this space or the zero vector by irreducibility. Since $T$ is nontrivial as this Hom space is nontrivial, the image must be all of this space, and hence $T$ must be surjective.

Comment: Why can one assume the induced representation is irreducible?

Comment: @LSpice I agree, if the induced is irreducible then it is OK. Can we replace the induced by a subquotient having $K$-fixed vectors, and also state that the Hom-space is one-dimensional? Otherwise I agree with Peter's argument.